# Swift very long enum with one different case: how to deal with that?

Tags: swift

I try to make enum from HTML colours. First moment I thought it will be nice and simple but I hit a wall. Colors could be defined as name: `moroon`, `gray`, `grey` (same value) or RGBA string `#00000000`. I started from:

```
enum HTMLColor {
    case aliceblue
    case antiquewhite
    case aqua
    case aquamarine
    case azure

    //..... many, many names and at the end:

    case custom(String)
}
```

OK. Because of last `custom` and some double names (gray, grey) I cannot define raw type. So I added two long switches name and hexString:

```
    public var name:String {
        switch self {
        case .aliceblue: return  "aliceblue"
        case .antiquewhite: return  "antiquewhite"
        case .aqua: return  "aqua"
        case .aquamarine: return  "aquamarine"
        case .azure: return  "azure"

        //..... many, many names and at the end:

        case .custom(let string): return string
        }
    }
```

Similar with hexString – but in place of name I can return `"#00000000"`.

But now I have not idea how to implement `init(from string:String)` or `init(from decoder:Decoder)`. I would like to have

```
let azure = HTMLColor(from: "azure")
```

and got `.azure`

or:

```
let custom = HTMLColor(from: "#AB0023FF")
```

and got `.hexString(hexValue)` to use them as:

```
switch color {
    case .custom(let string): makeRealColorFromString(string)
    default: makeRealColorFromString(color.hexString)
}
```

Maybe `enum` is not a best idea for this particular problem?

Comment: While you can probably get an enumeration to do what you want, I suspect it is not your best choice. I would suggest you take a look at UIColor found as part of the Apple UI kit. I'm not saying you should use it (since I don't know the details of your application), but take a look at it's API. It may give you some ideas on how to design your enumeration or class. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `struct` for this. Like this:

```
struct HTMLColor: RawRepresentable, Codable {
    typealias RawValue = String
    var rawValue: String
}
```

And then you can add color cases anywhere you want and whichever you want:

```
extension HTMLColor {
    static let aliceblue = HTMLColor(rawValue: "aliceblue")
    static let antiquewhite = HTMLColor(rawValue: "antiquewhite")
    static let aqua = HTMLColor(rawValue: "aqua")
    static let aquamarine = HTMLColor(rawValue: "aquamarine")
    static let azure = HTMLColor(rawValue: "azure")

    //..... many, many names, and even:

    static let customBlack = HTMLColor(rawValue: "#00000000")
}
```

And now you can use `HTMLColor.azure` or do `let custom = HTMLColor(rawValue: "#AB0023FF")` anywhere in your code.

And for `RawRepresentable` default encoding/decoding would be in/from `RawValue` type (here it's `String`).

Comment: OK. I added static let  hexValues:[String:String] = ["aliceblue" : "#F0F8FFFF", .....] to have hex values, dynamic var hexValues and it's not nice but works.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, `enum` (although intuition suggests so) may be not the best option for implementing this. Having said that, if you *do* want to use an enum you could do something like this:

```
enum HTMLColor: CaseIterable, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    case white
    case black
    // ... others
    case custom(String)

    static var allCases: [HTMLColor] {
        return [.white, .black] // All except .custom here
    }

    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .white: return  "white"
        case .black: return  "black"
        // ... others
        case .custom(let string): return string
        }
    }

    var hexString: String {
        switch self {
        case .white: return  "#FFFFFFFF"
        case .black: return  "#00000000"
        // ... others
        case .custom(let string): return string
        }
    }

    init(stringLiteral: String) {
        self = HTMLColor.allCases.first(where: { ($0.name == stringLiteral) || ($0.hexString == stringLiteral) }) ?? .custom(stringLiteral)
    }

}
```

Essentially, we conform to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` which means that we can initialize our enum with a string literal. Then in the initializer, we search names & hexValues for a match or return a `.custom`

It's not a complete or a production-ready solution by any means (one obvious thing that is missing is that it doesn't match hex values that omit the alpha component or the '#' prefix) but you get the idea...

Then we can use it like this:

```
let c1: HTMLColor = "#FFFFFFFF"
let c2: HTMLColor = "#F2F2F2FF"
let c3: HTMLColor = "black"

print(c1) // --> .white
print(c2) // --> .custom("#F2F2F2FF")
print(c3) // --> .black
```

Finally, you could even extend support for Int literal initalization (so you could do `let c: HTMLColor = 0xF2F2F2FF` for example) or tackle all code repetition with tools like [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery)

Comment: It is exactly same approach I've tried; indeed, enum seems to wrong idea ;) thank you!